# Calculating T(v) knowing v1,v2,v3 and v4

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I am struggling to understand how to interpret this problem. I've been given this information about the linear transformation T:

T(v1)=−t^3−t^2−1

T(v2)=−t^3−t^2−t−1

T(v3)=−t^3−t^2−1

T(v4)=t^3+t^2−t+1

and that the vector v has these coordinates in the basis B:

[v]_B= \begin{bmatrix}
    2 \\
    -1 \\
    2\\
    2
\end{bmatrix}

I have also been given the information that a vector space V has a base B that consists of v1, v2, v3, and v4.

Based on this I am to calculate T(v) and determine Ker(T).

I started out by writing the equations I was given in a matrix and putting v_B as my right-hand side. Then I performed row operations on that matrix but having done that, it feels like it makes no sense as the matrix contradicts itself. Based on the matrix the coefficient in front of t should equal 3 but row four indicates that the coefficient before t should be -4. Probably I've interpreted the problem wrong from the beginning, and the matrix, therefore, makes no sense. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to go about this problem in a more structured way than I've done?

How I represented the problem with a matrix:

[image]

I would be grateful for any help, thanks in advance!

/Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be any vector spaces over the same field $F$, and let $T \colon X \rightarrow Y$ be a linear transformation. If $\left( x_1, \ldots, x_n \right)$ is a basis for $X$, and if $x \in X$ has the unique representation $x = \sum_{i = 1}^n \alpha_i x_i$ as a linear combination over $F$ of the basis vectors, then we have the formula
>   $$
> T(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \alpha_i T \left( x_i \right).
> $$

In your case, 
$$
v = 2v_1 - v_2 + 2v_3 + 2v_4.
$$
Therefore 
$$
\begin{align}
T(v) &= 2 T \left( v_1 \right) - T \left( v_2 \right) + 2 T \left( v_3 \right) + 2 T \left( v_4 \right) \\ 
&= 2 \left( -t^3 - t^2 - 1 \right) - \left( -t^3 - t^2 - t -1 \right) + 2 \left( -t^3 - t^2 - 1 \right) + 2 \left( t^3 + t^2 - t + 1 \right) \\
&= -t^3 - t^2 - t -1.
\end{align}
$$

Please check the algebraic calculation in the above once again.